# No compiler error when using wrong type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ionic3, angular5, static-typing

I'm using Ionic 3 (Angular 5), and even though I specify the type of a variable or a function, it doesn't matter what I use, it always works just as it would in plain JS, i.e. no error are produced. Do I need to configure some settings file (e.g. tsconfig.json) or am I missing something? I can even do e.g.:

```
foo : string;

foo = someObject as SomeNonExistentClass;
```

What's interesting is that when I run `ionic serve`, the errors are actually shown, but when I resave one of the files which reported an error,  all the errors are gone. Also happens from time to time on a new save/recompile.

Answer (score 0):

probably are lint errors, lint errors does not appear when running the ionic serve, I suggest you install an extension in your ts-lint code editor, which would show you lint errors at programming time.